# KOMA Script scrlttr2 toaddress lines are near

Tags: line-spacing, scrlttr2

I can't find the variable to set the distance between two lines in the `toadress` field. In my letter the lines are clearly closer to each other than in the rest of the letter.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\setkomavar{toname}{%
Somebody in toname
}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{%
some place in toaddress 3b\\
Code-Townname
}
```

[image: the too near toaddress line]

Can you see the difference between the normal distance between `toname` and `toaddress` and the second line of `toaddress` called `Code-Townname`?

---

you are right. I tested your file and it looks quite nice althrough i had a slight feeling (but didn't realy see it) that its a bit the same. So i played arround and found out that its a combination of `fontsize > 11` and the `\large` variable i use in the `toaddress` box.

have a look to this file:

```
% compile with lualatex
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt, % <-----Increase this value to see it more clearly
  paper=a4,
  parskip=full,
  enlargefirstpage=off,
  fromalign=right,
  fromphone=off,
  fromrule=off,
  addrfield=on,
  backaddress=off,
  foldmarks=no,
  pagenumber=false,
  refline=nodate,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\addtokomafont{toname}{\large}    % <----- i added this two lines to get a larger to 
\addtokomafont{toaddress}{\large} % <----- address than the letter font has

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{street number\\code place}
\setkomavar{location}{\usekomavar{date}}
\setkomavar{toname}{SOMEBODY in toname}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{SOME place in toaddress 3b\\CODE-Townname}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}
\opening{TesT opening,}
\lipsum
\closing{mfg}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I can decrease my fontsize to 11pt to solve it but i wold like to know if there is a value to seperate the two lines in `\addtokomafont{toaddress}` a bit...

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example that shows the problem?

Comment: The example needs to be compilable for us to reproduce the screenshot on our machine. It is possible that you have changed the font, that something in KOMA-script is broken or that something was broken in the past.

Comment: Maybe there is some space added between name and address by the class, not sure, no time to look at it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

I have reported the bug to Markus Kohm, so it is already fixed in the current prerelease (v3.22.2564) of KOMA-Script. You can install this version from the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801).

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=14pt,
    DIV=calc
    ]{scrlttr2}[2016/01/21]% needs version 3.22.2564 or newer
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{toname}{\large\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{toaddress}{\large}

\setkomavar{toname}{SOMEBODY in toname}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{SOME place in toaddress 3b\\CODE-Townname}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Hey}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

If the font of `toname` and `toaddress` should be set/changed in the same way, use the font element `addressee` instead:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=14pt,
    DIV=calc
    ]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{addressee}{\large}% use this element instead
%\addtokomafont{toname}{\large}    % <----- i added this two lines to get a larger to 
%\addtokomafont{toaddress}{\large} % <----- address than the letter font has

\setkomavar{toname}{SOMEBODY in toname}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{SOME place in toaddress 3b\\CODE-Townname}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Hey}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nevertheless the font elements `toname` and `toaddress` do not work as expected. As you can see in the follwing example, changing only the font element `toname` affects the element `toaddress` in the address field too:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=14pt,
    DIV=calc
    ]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{toname}{\sffamily}

\setkomavar{toname}{SOMEBODY in toname}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{SOME place in toaddress 3b\\CODE-Townname}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Hey}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As a **workaround for versions older than 3.22.2564** you can patch command `\@addrfield` to solve both problems:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=14pt,
    DIV=calc
    ]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{toname}{\large\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{toaddress}{\large}

\setkomavar{toname}{SOMEBODY in toname}
\setkomavar{toaddress}{SOME place in toaddress 3b\\CODE-Townname}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\@addrfield}
    {\usekomafont{toname}{\usekomavar{toname}\\}}
    {{\usekomafont{toname}{\usekomavar{toname}\\}}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd{\@addrfield}
    {\usekomafont{toaddress}{\usekomavar{toaddress}}}
    {{\usekomafont{toaddress}{\usekomavar{toaddress}\endgraf}}}% copied from the fix by Markus
    {}{\PatchFailed}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Hey}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: i added this part:

`\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\@addrfield}
    {\usekomafont{toname}{\usekomavar{toname}\\}}
    {{\usekomafont{toname}{\usekomavar{toname}\\}}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd{\@addrfield}
    {\usekomafont{toaddress}{\usekomavar{toaddress}}}
    {{\usekomafont{toaddress}{\usekomavar{toaddress}\endgraf}}}% copied from the fix by Markus
    {}{\PatchFailed}`

That works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\strut`s help with spreading contents and providing a consistent baseline:

```
\setkomavar{toaddress}{\strut SOME place in toaddress 3b\\ \strut CODE-Townname}
```

[image]